# Font in inkscape is revolting instead of smooth

Tags: inkscape, svg

I used Inkscape to add the text *Prostanthera ovalifolia* to a PDF generated by R and it came out jagged with bits missing:

[image: The font is jagged and bits missing]

The SVG file can be found online [here](https://svgshare.com/i/umg.svg).

Inkscape was re-installed a few days ago on a Windows 10 machine.
I have occasionally been editing similar PDFs created by R for several years and not met this problem.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's hard to say without examining the PDF file. What I suspect is that the text is just outlines generated by R, and not an actual editable text object, and somehow the outlines have become messed up, possibly due to insufficient/loss of precision either during the PDF import process, or when outputting the graphic from R.

Comment: A simple fix would be to delete and retype the text natively in Inksape. Whether this is practical or not depends on how much text there is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The text "Prostanthera ovalifolia" has been added in Inkscape, it did not come from R.

Comment: then I'm at a loss. Can you share the SVG?  Upload it to svgshare.com and post the link here. You don't need to sign up for an account.

Comment: Now on svgshare.com named Prostanthera ovalifolia and maybe this is the link: But the link will not copy!

Comment: I've found it, it's here https://svgshare.com/i/umg.svg

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr

Answer (score 19):

After examining the SVG, I notice that you have a custom dash stroke set on the text.

Select the text object, go into the Fill and Stroke panel (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), then into the Stroke Style tab

Set the dashes to a normal solid stroke

[image]Click to see larger

**Note:** If you don't want a stroke, just remove it in the Stroke Paint tab. Hit the X to remove the stroke.

As to how this happened you may have just accidentally hit it, or the text tool has inherited the dashed stroke you used on another object.

If the latter is the case, then to prevent this from happening in future go into *Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text*, and set the option that says "This tools own style". If you have it set to "Last used style" it will inherit the last style you used, i.e. a dashed stroke.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all that @billykerr. You're wonderful. The stroke was inherited from the dashed lines I had added.

Comment: @RuthP - yeah I thought so.  Did you see my last edit? I added more info on how to stop that from happening.

Comment: Yes I did that thanks! @billykerr